# SSIS: Trying to configure branching logic in Foreach loop

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, ssdt-bi

Full disclosure: I posted this on SQL Server Central yesterday but got no answers. I hope someone here can assist me.

I'm working on importing flat files into a database. I have used a Foreach loop in an SSIS project in SQL Server Data Tools for SQL 2012. have just started developing these packages so please let me know of any rookie mistakes I need to correct.

If even one of the files has not been updated in the last day, I want the processing to stop and an alert email sent out.

Schematically, the control flow I need is as follows:

```
[Foreach loop] ---> Failure ----> Send import failure email
|
| 
↓
Success
↓
[Proceed with import]
```

I have tested with setting one of the files to be too old, on purpose, to trigger the failure. What happens now, though, is that I get the Failure email but I also get a SQL error from a task in the `Proceed with import` section, as if the Success path has also been followed.

In both success and failure cases, I have tried to set Precedence Constraints with "Expression and Constraint" as the Evaluation operation, with a Boolen value set for the expressions. `@[User::ProcessFile]= False` or `@[User::ProcessFile]= True` depending on the case.

Could someone explain (or direct me to a reference explaining) how to make sure the SSIS package is following the path I expect it to?

EDIT: Picture of control flow is below.

[image]

Comment: There's a few different problems in here. Which one are you trying to solve? Can you pop a picture of what your control flow looks like? [SSC question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1760165-2799-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited my question to add a picture of the control flow.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. In my expressions for the precedence constraints, I had been using something like the following: @[User::ProcessFile] = False - but to check the value it seems this is needed: @[User::ProcessFile] == False. I figured it might be something basic like this that I just didn't realize due to inexperience with SSDT.

Comment: As opposed to `@[User::ProcessFile] == False`